# how to display the calculation result of comboboxes

Tags: c#

I just started learning c# and still struggle in it.
I have a combobox1 with options: "basic ($10/w)","regular ($15/w)" and "premium ($20/w)".
Combobox2: "3 months", "12 months", and "24 months"
A "calculate" button and a textbox1.

What I'd like to achieve: when users make selections in combobox 1 &2, after clicking "calculate", the result will be shown on textbox1.
For example, if a user selects "basic ($10/w)" and "3 months", they will see "120" in the textbox1.

Update:
I believe I have made it!!!
Here is part of the code I used:

```
    private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index1 = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        int index2 = comboBox2.SelectedIndex

        if (index1 == 0 && index2 == 0)
        {
            int result = 10 * 4 * 3;
            textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code you have tried?

Comment: Use a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) statement

Comment: "convert the selected items in comboboxes into integers" - No, don't do this. This is always a beginner's mistake. Have an array that contains the values you need at the same index as the `ComboBox` and just reference that.

Comment: The code you wrote essentially does nothing - it gets the combo-box value, then searches for it in the combo-box items to get an index, then sets the combo-box selection to that same item.

Comment: You can directly use `comboBox1.SelectedIndex` from `button1_Click` method. Don't need to set `comboBox1.SelectedIndex=index1`, SelectedIndex would be automatically changed when user select item from combobox.

Comment: @ebattulga I can't use comboBox1.SelectedIndex in button1_Click. It says "...doesn't exist in the current context."

Comment: @luciagao - That doesn't make sense. Can you please post your full code?

Comment: @Enigmativity that's not the way to ho, IMHO. You can use objects as items in combobox items collection, see Caius answer below and my comment on its answer for a way to avoid databinding and get the same result

Then you can get the selected value without having to look up in an array/list and risk that combobox items and the list are out of sync. 
I would not teach to a beginner a way that sooner or later will be a source of bug. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @GianPaolo - I try to make the UI as dumb as possible. I start with the array, use it to populate the UI, and then revert back to using the array asap. I try to involve the UI as little as possible. The separation of concerns like this makes the coding far simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Data binding makes situations like this easier

```
gasTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
gasTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
gasTypeComboBox.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, int> {
  { "basic", 10 },
  { "regular", 15 },
  { "premium", 20 }
}.ToList();

lengthComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
lengthComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
lengthComboBox.DataSource = new Dictionary<string, int> {
  { "1 month", 4 },
  { "2 months", 8 },
  { "3 months", 12 }
}.ToList();
```

This code creates, for each combo, a list of KeyValuePair where the Key property is the string we show and the Value is the int that the string is "worth". It tells the combo what to show, what to return when we ask it for what is selected, and assigns the list to the combo so it can show the items

By telling the combo what the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties are it knows what to display (the string it finds inside the KVP's Key) and what to return when we ask for SelectedValue (the int it finds in the KVP's Value)

I use a dictionary as a temporary container; it has a nice way of init the values - `{ {key1,value1}, {key2, value2}, ... }` and I ToList it to turn it from a `Dictionary<string, int>` into a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` because you can't bind to a dictionary but you can bind to a list

And then for the calculation, we just pull the selected values in each combo and cast them back to the ints  we know them to be

```
(int)lengthComboBox.SelectedValue * (int)gasTypeComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

The result of this is an int, so if you're assigning it to the text string of a text box, call ToString on it or append an empty string

```
some.Text = "" +  ((int)lengthComboBox.SelectedValue * (int)gasTypeComboBox.SelectedValue);
```

Side note it's probably also worth setting your combo DropDownStyle to drop down list so the user can't type in it

Comment: thx very much for your detailed answer! but we haven't learned anything about database yet so I need to find another way to work this out. thx anyway for the pre-knowledge!

Comment: nice answer, upvoted. @Luciagao, you can get the same result just adding each KeyValuePair to the Items collections, avoiding the databind subject which is probably something you still haven't learned (and no, is not related to database, at least in the way it is used in this anwser)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it's homework for a programming 101 so has to be very basic. I like enigmativity's suggestion

```
var prices = new[]{10,20,30};
var weeks = new[]{12,52,104}; //12 months is 52 weeks not 48, by the way
var result = prices[typeCombo.SelectedIndex]*weeks[lengthCombo.SelectedIndex];
```

Comment: I like Enigmativity's suggestion too. He's a smart guy. ;-)

Comment: that helped a lot! much neater and simpler than mine! thx very much!

Answer (score -1):

When this line excecutes

```
string result1 = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

you are obtaining the value selected of the combobox, lets say "regular ($15/w)"
then the line

```
int index1 = comboBox1.FindString(result1);
```

it return the index of the string in the combobox, in this case 1, supposing that is the second element.
Then:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index1;
```

You are setting the selected index of the combobox to 1, wich is redundant because you got the selected item in the first line.

I created an example with the problem you exposed, using the function substring to get the numeric values direct from the string of the combobox, this function goes in the click evento of the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string typeGasString = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string timePayString = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string typeGas = typeGasString.Substring(typeGasString.IndexOf("$") + 1, 2).Trim();
        string typePay = timePayString.Substring(0, 2).Trim();

        int gasPrice = Int32.Parse(typeGas);
        int gasPay = Int32.Parse(typePay);

        textBox1.Text = ((gasPay * 4) * gasPrice).ToString();
    }
```